# Сломалась табуляция VS Code Python

Tags: python

В программе VS Code всё нормально по табуляции, но если например вписать ту же функцию где угодно, код не будет работать, так как в IDLE табуляция в 2 раза больше. Вообщем, табуляция в VS Code и в IDE отличаются, почему? Ставил табсайз на 4, потом вернул обратно на 2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: ...]

Comment: `Ставил табсайз на 4, потом вернул обратно на 2. ` - это не решило вашу проблему?

Comment: не решило, табсайзы там и там отличаются, как вообще бороться с этим?

Comment: Значит у вас там отступ символами табуляции. Замените на пробелы. В vscode внизу справа в строке состояния нажать на "Пробелов: 2" (или сколько будет написано), в открывшемся меню выбрать "Преобразовать отступ в пробелы" (Convert Indentation to Spaces), сохранить.